# Selecting a dynamic range with ".setrange"

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm trying to Sort (with.sort) the data (entirerow) using .setrange.  However the Dynamic range I have selected in not getting sorted/picked up correctly.

The Dynamic are

```
LngFristrow = 8

FundColumn = 39

LngLastRow = 2973
```

So basically I want to take all the rows from 8 to 2973 and sort them.  Here is what I currently have.  I would be grateful if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong - thanks.

```
.SetRange Range(Cells(lngFirstRow, Fundcolumn).EntireRow, _ 
         Cells(lngLastRow, Fundcolumn).EntireRow)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
.SetRange Cells(lngFirstRow, 1).Resize(lngLastRow-lngFirstRow+1).EntireRow
```

Comment: Hello Peter - we meet again.  Once again thanks for your support.

Comment: Hello Peter - we meet again.  Once again thanks for your support.  I get a "Run-time Error 1004" when I try that.  For some reason it is not taken the range.  Not sure how to get around this one.

Comment: Hi again! :-) I had a small mistake (used `Range` instead of `Cells`), it should work now...

Comment: That worked - thanks again.  Not sure why my code didn't work but your approach is very useful.  Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! I still remember the day when I learned about `.Resize` and `.Offset` for ranges - it makes live so much simpler compared to `Range(Cell(X1,Y1),Cells(X2,Y2))`! Looking at your code, I think the problem is that you use `.EntireRow` within the Range definition - which expexcts only two cells here. Place it after the `)` and it will most likely work...